# C# uri protocol

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm developing two apps with c# (ASP WinForm)

I need to send some parameters from web to the WinForm app. for this, I wrote a function that allows my App to create an URI Protocol for this connection:

```
    public static void RegisterURLProtocol(string protocolName, string applicationPath, string description)
    {
        RegistryKey myKey = Registry.ClassesRoot.CreateSubKey(protocolName);
        myKey.SetValue(null, description);
        myKey.SetValue("URL Protocol", string.Empty);
        Registry.ClassesRoot.CreateSubKey(protocolName + "\\Shell");
        Registry.ClassesRoot.CreateSubKey(protocolName + "\\Shell\\open");
        myKey = Registry.ClassesRoot.CreateSubKey(protocolName + "\\Shell\\open\\command");
        myKey.SetValue(null, "\"" + applicationPath+ "\" %1");
    }
```

I use this peace of code to call the function:

```
            RegisterURLProtocol("mAPP", Application.ExecutablePath, "mAPP Uri Protocol");
```

in ASP project i send parameters to my app like this:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Redirect("mAPP://MYPARAMETERS");
}
```

But nothing happens when i try to open my ASP page like this:

http://mydomain/BlankPage.aspx

how can I fix this?

Comment: what windows version are you running?

Comment: windows 10 anniversary update

Comment: I think you mean registering a Custom Uri Scheme to an application... There is no such thing as a Uri Protocol. Worth looking in MSDN: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa767914.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Windos 8 onwards you will have to add some more registry keys:

```
Registry.SetValue(
                $@"HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\{protocolName}",
                string.Empty,
                protocolValue,
                RegistryValueKind.String);

Registry.SetValue(
                $@"HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\{protocolName}",
                "URL Protocol",
                String.Empty,
                RegistryValueKind.String);

Registry.SetValue($@"HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\{protocolName}\shell\open\command", string.Empty, command, RegistryValueKind.String);


// detect win 8 and register as choosable protocol handler
Version win8Version = new Version(6, 2, 9200, 0);
if (Environment.OSVersion.Platform == PlatformID.Win32NT &&
    Environment.OSVersion.Version >= win8Version)
{
     Registry.SetValue(
                    $@"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\{protocolName}",
                    string.Empty,
                    protocolValue,
                    RegistryValueKind.String);

    Registry.SetValue(
       $@"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\{protocolName}\shell\open\command",
        string.Empty,
        command,
        RegistryValueKind.String);

    Registry.SetValue(
       $@"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\{protocolName}\Capabilities\URLAssociations",
        protocolName,
        protocolName,
        RegistryValueKind.String);

    Registry.SetValue(
        @"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\RegisteredApplications",
        protocolName,
        $@"SOFTWARE\{protocolName}\Capabilities",
        RegistryValueKind.String);
}
```